# Java HashSet remove item by its hash code

Tags: java, hash, set, hashset, hashcode

I have a class with its own hashCode() method. I am adding this class to a HashSet. How can I remove an item by its hashCode, without knowing the object itself?

For example, if I have the following code

```
HashSet<Data> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new Data(10, 5));
...
class Data {
    public int importantVal;
    public int notImportantVal;
    //... constructor ...
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return importantVal;
    }
}
```

and I knew the `importantVal` of a Data object, but not the object itself. How would I remove it? `set.remove(10)` does not work.

Best solution I can think of is to also override `equals()` to return if `importantVal` is the same, and then do `set.remove(new Data(10, anyPlaceholderValue))`

Comment: Simplest is `set.removeIf(v -> v.getImportantVal() == importantVal);`. Not sure why you're using that as the hash code.

Comment: Simplest, yes, but that won't be at all performant, because it will check the `importantVal` of every object in the set, rather than taking advantage of the fact that that's the hash code.

Comment: Maybe use a `HashMap<Integer, List<Data>>` instead of a `HashSet<Data>`.

Comment: whoever closed the question, the links you provided are completely useless. I think its assumed that I'm looking for a performant solution. I obviously know how to write a for each loop